# Hiding/Overriding base class method with params in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, abstract-class

I have an abstract class which has a method with params parameter as below. I want to override and hide this method with a method which takes certain number of parameters instead of params in inheriting class.

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
    public List<int> list = new List<int>();
    public void Add(params int[] numbers){
        list.AddRange(numbers);
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass{
    public override void Add(int a, int b, int c){
        base.Add(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

This works but Add function of base class is still visible to outside and Add function in the child class doesn't seem to override it. Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to override and hide this method with a method which takes certain number of parameters instead of params in inheriting class.

You can't. That would break inheritance. Consider the following code:

```
BaseClass bc = new ChildClass();
bc.Add(0, 1);
```

That *has* to compile - so what would you expect it to do? If you're expecting the method with 3 parameters to *replace* the original, then presumably you don't want that to compile - but the compile-time type of `bc` is just `BaseClass`, not `ChildClass`.

You can *overload* `BaseClass.Add` (you don't need `new` because it's not got the same signature as the base class method), but you can't *replace* it with a more restrictive form.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of other ways to implement this. I added 2 more abstract classes in the middle and made method of the base protected. One of them exposes the method and one hides. This makes my class diagram more complex.
There is also the way to throw exceptions when unwanted number of parameters are used but I won't feel safe with it.

Comment: @SirKurt: If each concrete class has a different set of exposed methods, the abstract base class (with presumably only protected methods) isn't much use from the client perspective. It may allow you some reuse of implementation, but it doesn't give much to the client abstraction.

Comment: Though if your only motivation is to reuse implementation, maybe just tell your clients to use composition instead of inheritance (or have them call a static utility method).